# how to use shadowBox as simple image slider without popup effects?

Tags: javascript, static, shadowbox

working with [Shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/options.html)

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
        Shadowbox.init();
</script>
```

have 3 images:

```
<a href="../resources/lasea/certified_training/bild1_37.png" rel="shadowbox[certifiedtraining]" title="Image!">Image1</a>
<a href="../resources/lasea/certified_training/bild2_37.png" rel="shadowbox[certifiedtraining]" title="Image!">Image2</a>
<a href="../resources/lasea/certified_training/bild3_37.png" rel="shadowbox[certifiedtraining]" title="Image!">Image3</a>
```

shadowbox pops it always up with grey background color. i want to turn this effect off and use just a simple image slider. how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Shadowbox config, set the overlayOpacity to 0.